# How can I use snmpwalk to determine what I'm able to monitor via SNMP on a device?

Tags: centos, snmp, icinga2

Let me preface this by saying I'm familiar with SNMP only in theory. This is my first time working with SNMP.

I'm trying to determine what variables can be monitored using SNMP on a Dell EMC ML3 Tape Library. My job uses icinga2 for monitoring hosts, with SNMP plugins enabled for certain hosts. I'm performing the snmpwalk from our icinga2 server running CentOS 7.This tape library is a new device and we don't know what can be monitored on it.
I've ran the following commands (as outlined in documentation I found from the employee previously working on this):

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c 1c1ng@2 -O -e 10.100.19.11
```

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c 1c1ng@2 10.100.19.11
```

The output was the same for both commands and is shown in this screenshot:
[image: snmpwalk output]

This output doesn't seem to show any variables we would be interested in, such as interfaces, temperatures, etc. My question is, how do I find the OIDs so I can determine what SNMP can monitor on this host? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you install MIB on the machine where you run `snmpwalk`?

Comment: No, I haven't. I've been trying to figure out how to download the MIB on my centos machine.

Comment: There are no mibs for the ML3, but the standard ones should be in `/usr/share/snmp/mibs` and supplied by the `net-snmp-libs` package.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use `snmpbulkwalk -v2 -c 1c1ng@2 -O -e 10.100.19.11 .` instead. The dot at the end forces it to run from the root node.

Without it, it will only search `SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2` which is what seems to have been returned.

However, if that is all that is returned, then that is all there is.

The install of a mib primarily permits the resolution of the OID's into meaningful text if all you are doing is receiving data.

A quick check of the manual, seems to suggest that it sends snmp traps, so  set that up on the nm station.

From a post on [Dell SNMP](https://www.dell.com/community/Dell-OpenManage-Enterprise/Discovery-of-SNMP-device-Dell-ML3-Library/td-p/6232450) says `We do not have an OID or MIB pack for the ML3 unit. You can still set up SNMP traps and perform an SNMP walk, but there is not an existing resource pack we could provide to you.`.

Comment: For some reason, running that snmpbulkwalk command doesn't do anything. I just get the help output for snmpwalk.

Comment: Running `snmpwalk 10.100.19.11 -c 1c1ng@2 -v2c . -On` works. It displays a TON of OIDs. I'm assuming I need to have the MIB installed in order to view each variable by name?

Comment: The `-On` switch says to print the OIDs numerically, just get rid of it and they will become meaningful.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you!